# Error is occurring during execution of procedure in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am getting the error during executing the below procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_SUMIT (P_FEED IN FEED.FEED_ID%TYPE, P_OPCO_ID IN FEED.OPCO_ID%TYPE)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE V_PCF_PATTERN FEED.PCF_PATTERN%TYPE;
DECLARE CURSOR C_FEED FOR SELECT PCF_PATTERN FROM FEED WHERE FEED_ID=P_FEED AND OPCO_ID=P_OPCO_ID;
  OPEN C_FEED;
  LOOP
    FETCH C_FFED INTO V_PCF_PATTERN;   
    EXIT WHEN C_FEED%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_PCF_PATTERN);
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE C_FEED;
 END;
```

Error logs :

```
3/1            PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one of the following:

   begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete
   exists prior external language
The symbol "begin" was substituted for "DECLARE" to continue.

4/1            PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one of the following:

   begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete
   exists prior
```

Please assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DECLARE` statements should be after `AS` keyword.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE P_SUMIT (P_FEED IN FEED.FEED_ID%TYPE, P_OPCO_ID IN FEED.OPCO_ID%TYPE)
    AS
       V_PCF_PATTERN FEED.PCF_PATTERN%TYPE;
       CURSOR C_FEED IS SELECT PCF_PATTERN FROM FEED WHERE FEED_ID=P_FEED AND OPCO_ID=P_OPCO_ID;
    BEGIN
      OPEN C_FEED;
      LOOP
        FETCH C_FEED INTO V_PCF_PATTERN;   
        EXIT WHEN C_FEED%NOTFOUND;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_PCF_PATTERN);
       END LOOP;
       CLOSE C_FEED;
     END P_SUMIT;
/
```

Comment: I also answered the same and some one downvoted. So I removed it. Still wonder why downvotes and that too without reasons.

Comment: Thanks Mahswaran for your resposone...But I am still getting the error
`8/15           PLS-00201: identifier 'C_FFED' must be declared
8/9            PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored`

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for an explicit cursor here, or for parameters to be prefixed with "p_". Implicit cursors are quicker and more robust to write, and perform better.

```
create or replace procedure p_sumit (
  feed_id in feed.feed_id%type,
  opco_id in feed.opco_id%type)
as
begin
  for c_feed in (
    select pcf_pattern
    from   feed
    where  feed_id = p_sumit.feed_id and
           opco_id = p_sumit.opco_id)
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line(c_feed.pcf_pattern);
  end loop;
end;
```